# Docker Private Registry: connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Unable to connect to local docker repo.

Here is the docker compse file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    container_name: registry
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /home/user/auth/registry.password
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

I get the following error when I run `docker login localhost:5000` :

```
> Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:5000/v2/: dial tcp [::1]:5000: connect: connection refused
```

Note that: `/home/user/auth/registry.password` file exist

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth:

> Warning: You cannot use authentication with authentication schemes
> that send credentials as clear text. You must configure TLS first for
> authentication to work.

So, either secure authentication or no authentication at all.

If you do want basic authentication with no TSL, your only option is to use a webserver in front, which can do that, and proxy requests to a plain registry with no authentication at all. See examples for [apache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/apache/) and [nginx](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/nginx/), and remove all the SSL configuration if you don't need it.
This may look like a bit of work, but it's not that difficult and is very flexible.

Another option is to use TSL, and if you don't already have a valid certificate for your domain you can [configure the registry with a Let's Encrypt certificate](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#letsencrypt), or you can [set it up with a self-signed certificate](https://medium.com/@ifeanyiigili/how-to-setup-a-private-docker-registry-with-a-self-sign-certificate-43a7407a1613) (only do that if you are sure this registry is isolated from the external world).